# Pasting seems to be disabled in html code (but there is nothing actually disabling it)

Tags: html, css, formatting, copy-paste

I have some html with js, css, etc that is fine with the exception that you cannot paste into the input boxes.  There is nothing obvious to me as what is causing this.  Now, I have found a semi-solution:

There is a line of code that looks like this:

```
*{margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
```

If I remove that line OR just the overflow portion I can paste into the input boxes...However, it destroys the layout and formatting of the page.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: More code to see would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to post a reproduction of the problem somewhere, preferably on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). The line of CSS you show should have *no effect* on pasting. Presumably there's some JavaScript interfering somewhere, for some reason.

Comment: So you can type into the input boxes, just not paste?  And if you remove the overflow, you can all of a sudden paste?  That's *weird*, does it repro on all browsers?

Comment: Yes...it's very bizarre...but it happens in every browser...oh, and copying is not affected at all...so I tried it in JS Fiddle, and it worked fine for me but didn't work for two others...truly strange...but here's the link   http://jsfiddle.net/NqcCH/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about some more specific styles. If overflow:hidden is causing this problem on your INPUTs then only use it on elements that you know for sure you want to prevent overflow. INPUTs generally need to have overflow visible to work right.

Try this?

```
*{margin:0; padding:0; }
DIV,HTML,BODY{overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much...ultimately the solution was directly related to the overflow.  Conceptually the suggestion by Matthew was the right path.  I had to remove the overflow from the existing style and place it in the various styles where it actually belonged.  Irt wasn't an easy task for a novice like myself, but the upside is I now understand it conceptually.  Thanks to everytone for helping me out with this!

Comment: Is this the accepted answer then? If so, you should click the checkbox to the left.